# phpmyadmin - can't type in query box

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Might be dumbest question ever, but....

In phpmyadmin I select my database and then go to the SQL tab where I see 
`Run SQL query/queries on database masontxc_wo6691:` at the top of my query window, but it won't let me type anything!

I have logged into phpmyadmin with every account/login i can find or create, all let me in, but none allow me to query the db.

`phpmyAdmin Version - 3.5.8.2`

Database Server -

Server: `Localhost via UNIX socket`

Software: `Percona Server`

Software version: `5.5.40-36.1-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 36.1, Revision 707`

Comment: Do you get an error in java script console in the browser?

Comment: It was CHROME!!  I switched to Firefox and it behaved as expected. Sorry about crying wolf.      That said, in Chrome I had cookies and popups enabled and I saw no error messages.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any Chrome extension active?